# I want to update a property in my primaryviewmodel from the viewmodel that I use in my usercontrol

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding

I am trying to update my treeview in primary viewmodel everytime I add an object to my database in my usercontrol viewmodel.

This is the code in my primary viewmodel

```
public class RechtbankenRechtersViewModel : Basis
{
    IUnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork(new RechtContext());
    private ObservableCollection<Rechtbank> _rechtbanken;
    private IntroRechtbankenEnRechters intro = new IntroRechtbankenEnRechters();
    private UserControl _control;
    private ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem> _tree;
    private TreeViewItem _treeItem;

    public TreeViewItem TreeItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _treeItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _treeItem = value;
           
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public UserControl Control
    {
        get 
        {
            return _control; 
        }
        set 
        {
            _control = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem> Tree
    {
        get 
        {
            return _tree;
        }
        set
        {
            _tree = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
   
    public ObservableCollection<Rechtbank> Rechtbanken
    {
        get
        {
            return _rechtbanken;
        }
        set
        {
            _rechtbanken = value;
            BouwBoom();
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public override string this[string columnName] => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public RechtbankenRechtersViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Rechtbanken en rechters";
        Tree = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem>();
        TreeItem = new TreeViewItem();
        Rechtbanken = new ObservableCollection<Rechtbank>(uow.RechtbankRepo.Ophalen(x => x.Rechters));
        IntroRechtbankenEnRechters intro = new IntroRechtbankenEnRechters();
        Control = intro;
        
    }

    //gaat de lijst van Tree opvullen met treeviewitems
    public void BouwBoom()
    {
        foreach (var rechtbank in Rechtbanken)
        {
            TreeViewItem parent = new TreeViewItem() { Header = rechtbank.Naam, Tag = rechtbank.RechtbankID, Name="Rechtbank"};
            foreach (var rechter in rechtbank.Rechters)
            {
                parent.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Rechter - " + rechter.Voornaam + " " + rechter.Achternaam, Tag = rechter.RechterID, Name = "Rechter" });
            }
            Tree.Add(parent);
        }
    }
```

The Method BouwBoom is what fills my treeview since I struggled with it in the xaml(not much of a designer)

when opening the usercontrol i pass through the tag so that i can load the correct data into an object

my usercontrol viewmodel looks like this

```
public class OperatiesRechterViewModel : Basis
{
    private RechtersRechtbanken context = (RechtersRechtbanken)Application.Current.Windows[1];
    private Rechtbank _selectedRechtbank;
    private ObservableCollection<Rechtbank> _rechtbanken;
    private Rechter _rechter;
    IUnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork(new RechtContext());
    public override string this[string columnName] => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public Rechter Rechter 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _rechter; 
        }

        set
        {
            _rechter = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

   

    
    public Rechtbank SelectedRechtbank
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedRechtbank;
        }

        set
        {
            _selectedRechtbank = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Rechtbank> Rechtbanken
    {
        get
        {
            return _rechtbanken;
        }

        set
        {
            _rechtbanken = value;
        }
    }

    

    public OperatiesRechterViewModel()
    {
        Rechter = new Rechter();
        Rechtbanken = new ObservableCollection<Rechtbank>(uow.RechtbankRepo.Ophalen());
    }

    public OperatiesRechterViewModel(int id)
    {
        
        Rechter = uow.RechterRepo.ZoekOpPK(id);
        Rechtbanken = new ObservableCollection<Rechtbank>(uow.RechtbankRepo.Ophalen());
        SelectedRechtbank = uow.RechtbankRepo.Ophalen(x => x.RechtbankID == Rechter.RechtbankID).SingleOrDefault();
    }
    
    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        switch (parameter.ToString())
        {
            case "Toevoegen":
                if (Rechter.RechterID <= 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
 
            case "Wijzigen":
                if (Rechter.RechterID > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            return false;

            case "Verwijderen":
                if (Rechter.RechterID > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public string FoutmeldingInstellen()
    {
        string melding = "";
        if (SelectedRechtbank == null)
        {
            
        }
        return melding;
    }
    public void Toevoegen()
    {
        if (SelectedRechtbank != null)
        {
            Rechter.RechtbankID = SelectedRechtbank.RechtbankID;
            if (Rechter.Voornaam != "")
            {

                if (Rechter.Achternaam != "")
                {
                    uow.RechterRepo.Toevoegen(Rechter);
                    int ok = uow.Save();
                    if (ok > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Rechter is toegevoegd!");

                        ///refresh view in principe
                        context.DataContext = new RechtbankenRechtersViewModel();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //
                }
            }

            else
            {
                //foutmelding maken
            }
        }

        else
        {
            //foutmelding maken
        }
    }

    public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        switch (parameter.ToString())
        {
            case "Toevoegen":
                Toevoegen();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

As you can see here, I use the `application.current.windows` method to get the activated window and then I update it's datacontext when toevoegen(add) is pressed.

However I don't know if this is allowed in mvvm.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

for those who want to do the same thing just pass on the function to the constructor of the usercontrol viewmodel as an action then inside the uc viewmodel you can invoke it